# why is enchantment applyable on armor even tho i specified that it should be on weapon?

Tags: minecraft-forge

I have an enchantment that makes the target fly but i want it to be only on swords. but with my code i can also put it on armor and bows (and probably also other items).

```
public class LevitateEnchantment extends Enchantment {

public LevitateEnchantment(){
    super(Rarity.RARE, EnchantmentType.WEAPON, new EquipmentSlotType[]{EquipmentSlotType.MAINHAND});
}


@Override
public int getMinLevel(){
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getMaxLevel(){
    return 2;
}

@Override
public void onEntityDamaged(LivingEntity user, Entity target, int level) {
    LivingEntity target1 = (LivingEntity)target;
    target1.addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.LEVITATION, (2 + level) * 20));
}
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I used @Override on the function "canApply". Apparantly minecraft only checks this function in survival so thats why i thought it didn't work.